# Header across the page on zoom

Tags: html, css, header, zooming

http://jsfiddle.net/CPSKa/

On my site when ever I zoom in on to the header the line below the header starts to get shorter is there anyway I can prevent this from happening.

HTML Code:

```html
<div id="main_header">   
 <div id="main_header_wrapper">
     <a href="index.php"><img src="http://chattrd.com/maint/images/logo.png" alt="Chattrd"/></a>

 <nav id="navigation">
 <a href="index.php" class="nav_icon">Home</a>
 <a href="#" class="nav_icon">Blog</a>
 <a href="login.php" class="nav_icon">Login</a>
 <a href="#" class="nav_icon">Sign up</a>
 </nav>

 </div>
 </div>
```

CSS Code:

```css
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
#main_header{
background:#FFF;
padding:10px 0; 
margin:auto;
border-bottom:1px solid #c5c5c5;}

#main_header_wrapper{
width:900px;
margin:auto;}

nav#navigation{
font-family: Arial;
padding-top: 2px;
text-align: right;
font-weight: bold;
float: right;
display: inline;}

a.nav_icon{
color:#000;
-webkit-transition:background 0.2s ease-in;  
-moz-transition:background 0.2s ease-in;  
-o-transition:background 0.2s ease-in;  
transition:background 0.2s ease-in; 
padding: 14px 25px;
text-decoration: none;}

a.nav_icon:hover{
background: #990033;
color: #FFF;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
#main_header{
width:900px;
}
```

Comment: hmm strange, it did when i tryed it on your jsfiddle

Comment: Can you show me the JSfiddle please? Much appreciated if you can.

Comment: Ah yes the width did work but the wrapper now, no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

I think changing your `#main_header_wrapper` CSS to this should work:

```
#main_header_wrapper {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: auto; }
```

Having a fixed width of 900px was affecting the div after you zoom in past the width of the viewport. max-width keeps it in line.

Answer (score 0):

Set the css width of the main_header element to width: 100%;